# Why do PS1 calls inside a PS1 Script run when executed in Powershell, but are not executed when run as a Windows Scheduled Task?

Tags: windows, powershell, scheduled-tasks, call

I am running a Powershell script (TaskScript.ps1) using Powershell v4.0 (from Get-Host cmdlet) w/ File Version: 6.3.9600.17415 (Windows Explorer File Properties.) I am trying to run this script from a regularly scheduled task on Windows Server 2012 R2; the TaskScript.ps1 does this:

```
& .\OtherScript1.ps1
#... log messages to LogFile ...
& .\OtherScript2.ps1
#... log more messages to LogFile ..
```

When invoked manually in Powershell, the entire TaskScript.ps1 -- including calls to OtherScript1.ps1 and OtherScript2.ps1 -- execute as expected and logging to LogFile is executed as desired; that is, **after** OtherScript.ps1 and OtherScript2.ps1 complete.

However when TaskScript.ps1 is run from a Windows Scheduled Task, the script is run and LogFile is updated immediately without invoking OtherScript1 or OtherScript2 executing.

I've checked that:

- LogFile is clear before manually running the script and manually executing the Task
- running the script manually executes all of the included scripts as
  expected (each subscript has its own logging which has been checked)
- LogFile is written to (at the appropriate times) when executed manually (I've watched the output as it happens)
- The Scheduled Task is running and invoking TaskScript.ps1 (LogFile is updated whenever the task is run)
- TaskScript.ps1 is not executing other scripts when run through Task (regardless of if Task is run manually or is scheduled) -- OtherScript1.ps1 and OtherScript2.ps1 have logging that is not triggered when the Task is run, but is triggered when TaskScript.ps1 is manually run from directly within Powershell. `ie. powershell.exe .\TaskScript.ps1`
- LogFile is written to immediately when executed through the Task. No delay for the other two scripts; as happens when executing within Powershell.

I've tried a few methods for invoking the scripts within TaskCript.ps1 including the call operator syntax above, the Start-Process cmdlet and dot sourcing (which could work in this case, but is not preferred).

I've also tried temporarily adjusting the Execution Policy on the Scheduled Task using `-ExecutionPolicy Bypass` argument in my Task, thinking maybe the calls couldn't be invoked from within a script because of execution policy.

Some user [here](https://studiooflegend.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/SCK/pages/584286209/Design+Specifications?streamsSourceProduct=jira) had an issue with Windows Task Scheduler not liking script file off of local drive. In case it's relevant, my TaskScript.ps1, OtherScript1.ps1 and OtherScript.ps2 scripts (and others) are located on a local VHD (virtual disk) at P:\PathTo\Scripts\TaskScript.ps1.

This is what my task looks like:

```
Program/script: C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
Add arguments (optional): -NoProfile -NoLogo -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& Path\To\TaskScript.ps1"
```

Why won't OtherScript1.ps1 and Otherscript2.ps1 execute if TaskScript.ps1 is run from a Windows Scheduled Task but will run just fine if invoked manually in Powershell?

Comment: Did you set the working (or "start in") directory of the task to the folder that contains `OtherScript1.ps1`?

Comment: Ah! Apologies for the ignorance. I thought "Start In" meant something else. Word choice there is not great, but I have now set the directory now and it should work next time I have a chance to run it. Will report back and close this if so. Thanks.

Comment: Can confirm this did the trick.